# Vue.js method returning outdated array data

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a method `resolveMovieSessions` that receive `movieSessions` from an API and create a new collection of data based on the API result.

What I want to achieve is to transform the API data from this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "movieSessions": [
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-12 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-13 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 1"{
}
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-14 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-15 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-16 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-17 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-11 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-12 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-13 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-14 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {{
}
          "name": "Sala 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-15 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "startsIn": "2019-04-16 10:30:00",
        "movieTheaterRoom": {
          "name": "Sala 2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "2019-04-12": [{
    "room": "Sala 1",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }, {
    "room": "Sala 2",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }],
  "2019-04-13": [{
    "room": "Sala 1",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }, {
    "room": "Sala 2",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }],
  "2019-04-14": [{
    "room": "Sala 1",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }, {
    "room": "Sala 2",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }],
  "2019-04-15": [{
    "room": "Sala 1",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }, {
    "room": "Sala 2",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }],
  "2019-04-16": [{
    "room": "Sala 1",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }, {
    "room": "Sala 2",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }],
  "2019-04-17": [{
    "room": "Sala 1",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }],
  "2019-04-11": [{
    "room": "Sala 2",
    "hour": "10:30:00"
  }]
}
```

To achieve that, I made this code:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      movieSessions: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resolveMovieSessions(movieSessions) {
      const data = []

      if (movieSessions) {
        movieSessions.forEach((session) => {
          const startsInParts = session.startsIn.split(' ')

          const sessionDate = startsInParts[0]
          const sessionTime = startsInParts[1]

          if (!data.hasOwnProperty(sessionDate)) {
            this.$set(data, sessionDate, [])
          }

          data[sessionDate].push({
            room: session.movieTheaterRoom.name,
            time: sessionTime
          })
        })
      }

      return data
    },
    async loadMovieSessions() {
      const movieSessionsQuery = await apollo.query({
        query: MOVIE_SESSIONS_QUERY,
        variables: {
          movieId: this.movie.id,
          movieTheaterId: this.movieTheaterId
        }
      })

      const { data } = movieSessionsQuery
      const { movieSessions } = data

      this.movieSessions = this.resolveMovieSessions(movieSessions)
    }
  }
}
```

But when `this.resolveMovieSessions(movieSessions)` is called, the result is the initial value of the `data` const `const data = []`.

But inside the method, if i put a `console.log(data)` then I get the new collection, but a non-reactive one.

What going on?

Comment: I see three different uses of the identifier `data`. It might be easier to understand your intentions if you replaced those with unique names. For example, the line `this.$set(data, sessionDate, [])` doesn't appear to make any sense because `data` in that case is not reactive. (It's a local constant.)

Comment: So, what should I do? The data isn't reactive, but the same happens if I use a Vue.data property.

Comment: Sorry, @e200, but I can't follow your code clearly enough to understand your intentions (and offer help). That's why I suggested re-writing it (just slightly) to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I will improve it and the question.

Comment: In words, what is your goal of the function resolveMovieSessions for example? - I do somewhat see what your intentions are, but it seems like you are writing the code with too much overhead, so it seems harder than it needs to be 

Comment: I have already founded the bug, my question was updated. but I'm adding the problem I found now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `data` const was actually an array instead of an object: `const data = []`,I don't know why but this was the cause of the problem.

This is the working code:

```js
methods: {
  resolveMovieSessions(movieSessions) {
    const data = {}

    if (movieSessions) {
      movieSessions.forEach((session) => {
        const startsInParts = session.startsIn.split(' ')

        const sessionDate = startsInParts[0]
        const sessionHour = startsInParts[1]

        if (!data.hasOwnProperty(sessionDate)) {
          data[sessionDate] = []
        }

        data[sessionDate].push({
          room: session.movieTheaterRoom.name,
          hour: sessionHour
        })
      })
    }

    return data
  }
}
```